# prove that the language is not context free language

Tags: automata

Prove that the language $\{a^i b^j c^k $ $|$ $i>j>k \geq 0\}$ is non context free language without using the pumping lemma.

we could use some helpful facts to solve the question:

1. $A$ is a context free language and $B$ is regular, then $ A \cap B $ is context free.
2. $L_1$, $L_2$ are not context free languages, the intersection $L_1 \cap L_2$ is not context free as well.

Comment: The second helpful fact is wrong. Take two disjoint non-context-free languages.

Comment: if L1 is non context free language {a^i b^j c^k| i >=j>=k>=0} and L2 is non context free language {a^i b^j c^k| k>=j>=i >=0} the intersection of them is not context free

Comment: If $L_1 = L_2$ the helpful fact is also true. It's true for some pairs $L_1,L_2$, and false for others. I'd say that's not so helpful.

Comment: May I ask why you are interested in "without the pumping lemma"? Please explain, especially if you created this problem by yourself. Otherwise, can you provide a reference?

Comment: there is a question in "Sipser" book about that, the question asked to prove the language is non-context-free language by using fact ( a context free language intersection regular language is context free language ). the question in chapter 2 question # 2.30

Comment: The exercise 2.30 of my _Introduction to the Theory of computation_ starts with "Use the pumping lemma to show that the following languages are not context free."